# How to set the Image component in Next.js 13 to make the image appear on its original source size

Tags: next.js

I'm working in the NextJS 13 framework and I want to put some images in the website to appear in their original source size dynamically. I searched in the documents of the NextJS 13 Image component and I found only two options, the first one is to put a specific *width* and *height* like that:

```
        <Image
          src={img}
          width={178}
          height={178}
          alt=""
        />
```

the second one is to give the fill property a true value so it would *fill* its parent size which is also not what I want here becuase the parent is fixed size and could be much larger the the orginal image;

```
      <Image
          src={img}
          fill={true}
          objectFit="contain"
          alt=""
          className="translate-y-4"
       />
```

Is there a way to make the Image component in Next.js 13 to take the original size of its source? or in this case, I have to go with the regular  node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting the Image component props as following ;

```
    <Image
      src={img}
      width="0"
      height="0"
      sizes="100vw"
      className="w-auto h-auto "
      alt=""
    />
```

Hope it would help if anyone came across this issue and did not find a direct answer.